# How to use dockerfile-maven plugin with Azure CI/CD

Tags: java, maven, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I am trying to use `dockerfile-maven`plugin in Azure DevOps CI/CD. My plugin configuration is listed below:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
   <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${dockerfile.version}</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>default</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
            <goal>push</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <repository>host:port/group/app</repository>
      <tag>${project.version}</tag>
      <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
      <buildArgs>
         <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
      </buildArgs>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My settings.xml located into `~/.m2/`folder is listed bellow:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
        <servers>
                <server>
                  ...
                </server>
                <server>
                        <id>host:port</id>
                        <username>user</username>
                        <password>password</password>
                </server>
        </servers>
</settings>
```

When I run `docker login host:port`, it works as expected. But when I run `mvn deploy`, I get the following exceptions:

```java
[INFO] Image will be built as host:port/group/app:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] Sep 03, 2019 2:27:50 AM 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to 
{}->unix://localhost:80: Permission denied
Sep 03, 2019 2:27:50 AM 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
Sep 03, 2019 2:27:50 AM 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to 
{}->unix://localhost:80: Permission denied
Sep 03, 2019 2:27:50 AM 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
Sep 03, 2019 2:27:50 AM 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to 
{}->unix://localhost:80: Permission denied
Sep 03, 2019 2:27:50 AM 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80

[WARNING] An attempt failed, will retry 1 more times
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
    ...
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    ...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    ...
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    ...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    ...
```

Is there something to solve that issues?